# Twitter event triggers without actual event

Tags: javascript, php, twitter, web

I am facing a tricky problem with my code and hope to get some help on this. Below is a snippet of my code:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="http://www.myurl.com/" data-text="My text" data-via="Via">Tweet</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');</script>

<script>
    twttr.events.bind( 
          'tweet', 
              function (ev) {

        <?php
        $file = 'file.txt';
        $id = trim($_GET["id"]);
        $data = array("ID:$id", "CURRENT POSITION:$position", 'Twitter');
        file_put_contents($file, implode(" ",$data).PHP_EOL,FILE_APPEND);
        ?>
                            }
                    );
</script>
```

I can't understand why my **function (ev)** triggers every time the page loads. It should be only triggered once a tweet has been posted. Anyone knows where the problem lies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your *function* doesn't trigger, your **PHP** does. PHP is evaluated on the server, before the browser ever sees it. In fact, the browser has no idea what to do with PHP. What happens here is that your user loads the page, it gets processed by PHP, the PHP code is executed, and since nothing is outputted the function is empty. The code that the browser sees is:

```
<script>
twttr.events.bind( 
      'tweet', 
          function (ev) {

                        }
                );
</script>
```

If you inspect the source code in your browser you should see that the function is empty.

Comment: Thanks, got it. Maybe you could help me to write this PHP using AJAX?

Comment: The PHP you have will work, but it has to be in another file. You could put it in a file called something like `tweet.php` and then have your function do an AJAX call to `/tweet.php?id=<your_id_here>`, but the exact way you do the call depends on what sort of libraries you're using. Most people use jQuery for that sort of thing; you can take a look at its docs for more information. Be careful about malicious people intentionally using very large IDs to make your server write huge files, though.

Comment: I also use jQuery. Thanks, I'll try to make it work. Is there a way to protect myself from "malicious people intentionally using very large IDs to make your server write huge files"?

Comment: Well, I don't know how long the longest ID you expect there to be is, but a simple way is with a quick length test. If the length of the ID is longer than, like, 20-30 characters just `die()`. Also, in your PHP, where is your `$location` variable coming from? What exactly are you trying to log, and why?

Comment: <h1><?php echo $position ?><h1> - show actual position. And I am struggling with "share to advance in line". I came up with, writting in the txt file user's id & current possition to later mannualy change it. Example: if it was `if(isset($_GET["id"]) && trim($_GET["id"]) == '0'){ $position = "100"; }` then, after users id adds in my txt file I'll change his position to 99

Comment: I see... You may also want to look into getting a database that maps your IDs to your current position. Good luck! Don't forget to mark an accepted answer ;P